# jquery autocomplete ajax response separation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

**HTML part:**

```
  <form method="post" id="src-form" name="src-form" action="<?php echo $SCRIPT_NAME; ?>">

          <input id="src-location" name="src-location" autocomplete="off" />

          <input type="submit" name="src_submit" id="src_submit" value="Search" />

        </form>

    <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {

        $("input#src-location").autocomplete({

     source: "autosuggest-server.php"
        });

       $('input#src-location').focus(function()

        {       

                $(this).val('');


        });  

    });  

    </script>
```

**PHP part:**

```
<?php

include("db.php");

$return_arr = array();


$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city INNER JOIN country ON country.countryid = city.countryid where cityname like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%' ORDER BY cityname ASC limit 0,20"); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];

        $row_array['value'] = $row['cityname'].", ".$row['countryname'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }

echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

**JS:
Normal jquery autosuggest script**

**In the PHP file I've added:**

```
$row_array['value'] = $row['cityname'].", ".$row['countryname_'.$lang].",".$row['cityid'];
```

When I type in something it echos out the cityid as expected.  Is there any way to separate the cityid from the actual displayed value and feed it into a hidden input text field?

What I want to do is to search by the cityid but I don't want it to show in the search field.

Any other solutions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using an autocomplete plugin? please post a link to it.

Comment: @ftom2, OP has specified the tag `jquery-ui`. @OP: The easiest way I can think of is to modify your query to something like this `WHERE cityid = term`, this way searching will be by `cityid` and results will be by `cirtyname`

Comment: @Adnan OP wants both cityId and cityName, the seperation should be done in javascript.

Comment: @ftom2 - that's what I thought because the actual javascript prints out the result but I'm not sure how. I additionally included the js script that does the job. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess this is the critical part : if(msg != 0)

                  $("#ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(msg); But even if I manage to separate I have no idea how to set the value of a hidden field with it.

Comment: @Adnan - I want the user to type a city and get the city ID as well but that shouldn't be seen by the user. When they hit search the search is actually done by the cityID which was loaded into the hidden input text field.

Comment: @Peter, sorry your question is unclear to me. I think ftom2 has understood it better.

Comment: Setting a value to a hidden input is very easy just use: $('.hidden')).val(data); , How are you getting the message, as a string?

Comment: @Adnan - There is a website where people can search for properties. These properties are located in diffrent cities. E.g: You search for London.  You can see in the autocomplete London, United Kingdom. You hit search you can see the properties located in london. Because of language changes and other reasons I do not want to search in the database by city and country I want to search by city ID. So when You can see London, United Kingdom in the input search field and you hit search and the system actually seach all properties where the cityID is e.g.123456 (London, United Kingdom)

Comment: This is my problem. I need to get the city ID out of the response without the user seeing it.

Comment: @from2 - yes as a string. I know I can push the array with all 3 data, cityname, countryname, cityid. $row_array['value'] = $row['cityname'].", ".$row['countryname'].", ".$row['cityid']; but we need to do something in the javascript file which actually processes this information and puts it out.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you return the response as a JSON object, so in php you do:

```
$dataArray = ... //get city data where key=cityId, value=1, key=cityName, value=London etc.
echo json_encode($dataArray);
```

this will return something like:

```
{'cityId':'1','cityName':'London'}
```

Now in the javascript, define your ajax request to accept json by adding:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

and once you get the response message you can do:

```
$('#myHiddenField').val(msg.cityId);
var cityName = msg.cityName;
//do whatever you like with cityName
```

Comment: It's a json object. echo json_encode($return_arr); ---- Ok. In the javascript file I can see $("#ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(msg); Is there a way to trimm msg here before displaying it and do the hidden field valuation as you explein above?

Comment: What is the json format you are getting? (do alert or console.log() on the msg)

Comment: I don't know.  I'm a newbie. :$ Everything is in the code above. That's all I know.

Comment: do alert(msg) and let me know what you get

Comment: I'll get back later because I'm getting confused about the code. I need to sort it out. I'll do alert nad see what happens. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: I did alert(msg) but nothing happened. It didn't alert anything.

Comment: success: function(msg){  

            if(msg != 0)     alert(msg);

              $("#ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(msg);

            else

Comment: does the '$("#ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(msg)' happen?

Comment: that's what I'm thinkgin now. I've put ...html("test test test ") but it doesnt print test it prints the cities. Interestingly I don't even understand why it needs this autosuggest_script.js file.  There doesn't seem to be any connection with the actual jquery-ui.js... I've removed this file and the it didn't work. But still can't see the connection. Sorry for bothering you. This is something I hate to find out. Thank you for your replies and time.

Comment: sure, there is an up arrow next to the answer (top left) and also a 'v' sign to accept the answer.